# Why are holes (in a semi conductor) regarded as particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, solid-state-physics, electronics

Can I say that holes in a semiconductors are treated as current-carrying conventional direction ?

Comment: It's like positively charged carriers. They "flow" in the direction of the current.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very nice demonstration that you can treat holes as positively charged carriers in the Hall effect.

As you may know, to observe the Hall effect we place a semiconductor in a magnetic field and pass a current through it. We observe a polarization (voltage) at right angles to both the current and the magnetic field as a consequence of the Lorentz force of the magnetic field on the charge carriers.

Assuming that the field is into the page, a conventional current from left to right will result in a force that is pointing up. This is the force that will be experienced by the charge carriers - whether they are positive carriers traveling to the right, or negative ones traveling to the left.

But here is the crazy thing: the observed polarity of the polarization **depends on whether the charge carriers are positive or negative**. And although it is sometimes said that the holes are really "just electrons moving the other way, with a vacancy", if that was really the case you would see a force displacing the electrons. But you don't: you see a force displacing the positive charge.

If that doesn't surprise you, you haven't been paying attention. There is a nice lab write up at http://labs.physics.berkeley.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Hall_Effect_in_Semiconductor that includes diagrams and more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Holes are technically just vacancies,  but when an electron jumps into this vacancy,  one more hole is created,  but this constant filling up of a hole and creation of a hole appears as if the hole is moving,  that is it appears as if there are these +ve carriers which are moving in the direction of the current (opposite to that of the direction of electron) so we call holes as "particles."

.